# Positive definiteness via Folner sequence

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a countable discrete group. A function $\phi:\Gamma\to\mathbb{C}$ is called  **positively definite** if for every finite subset $F$ of $\Gamma$, the |F| by |F| matrix $(\phi(st^{-1}))_{s,t\in F}$ is positive.

Question: Assume that $\Gamma$ is amenable and $\{F_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Folner sequence of $\Gamma$. Suppose $\phi:\Gamma\to\mathbb{C}$ and for every $n$, the matrix $(\phi(st^{-1}))_{s,t\in F_n}$ is positive. Can we say that $\phi$ is positively definite?

Comment: ($s-t$ is not a very standard way to mean $s^{-1}t$ in a non-abelian group.) Anyway, the answer is yes by an elementary argument. Indeed, if $g\in G$, the probability that $gh\in F_n$, when $h$ is chosen randomly in $F_n$, tends to 1. Hence if $F$ is finite, the probability that $gh\in F_n$ for all $g\in F$, for $h$ random in $F_n$, tends to 1; in particular, it is eventually nonzero, which means that $F$ is contained in a left translate of $F_n$ for every $n$ large enough. This implies that the matrix $\phi(g^{-1}h)_{g,h\in F}$ is positive.